# Handle COM Ports in another class

Tags: python, serial-port, pyqt5

I am creating a Python project with PyQT5 which combines a class written by me and one written by someone else. The second class is opened in a new window to display data read from serial communication. I now have the problem, that when I close my program before the second window appears, the COM Port opened by the second class while instantiation is not closed properly, so that I can't run my program again. How can I handle this COM port so that it is not opened too soon or that it is closed properly?

My code looks like this:

```
class SecondWindow(SecondWindowClass):

    def closeThis(self):
        self.ser.close()
        self.close()
        self.first.show()

    def __init__(self, first):
        #SecondWindowClass.__init__(self)

        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        self.first = first
        self.ui = WindowTemplate()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

        print("Now opening COM port")
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout=1)
        print("COM1 opened")
        #line = self.ser.readline()  # first line is trash
        self.ser.flush()
        print("flushed COM11")
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.closeThis())

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def showSecond(self):
        self.second.show()
        self.hide()
        self.ui.end_button.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.nextPicture())

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Qt Designer')
        self.ui=uic.loadUi(uiFile, self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.show()
        self.second = SecondWindow(self)
        self.second.hide()
        self.ui.end_button.clicked.connect(lambda x:self.showSecond())
win = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
       QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `closeEvent`:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def closeEvent(self, evnt): # Use the closing event
        if isinstance(self.second, SecondWindow): # Check if instance already exists
            try: # Close port if possible
                self.second.ser.close()
                print("Port closed")
            except(RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
                print("no serial port")
[...]
```